# <html5> draw triangle around circle

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, graphic

I want if click the retacgle, draw a triangle around the circle.

source code like this...

but, triangle was not good each of positions..

How can i draw a triangle around the circle like attached image...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hccCQ.jpg

```
    ....
    ....



            ost = 30515;
            oen = 31570;

            //ost = 74147;
            //oen = 75664;

            color="255,0,0";
            av = (ost+oen) /2 ;
            x1 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*av);
            y1 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*av);
            x2 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*av)*1.07;
            y2 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*av)*1.07;

            var s={x1:x1,y1:y1,x2:x2,y2:y2};        
            triShape(s,color,true);

    ...
    ...
```

// draw a circle by retacgle

```
          function Shape_sub(s, k, color, draw){
            ctx_sub.save();
            //ctx_sub.rotate(Math.PI * 2 / 12); 
        ctx_sub.fillStyle='rgb('+color+')';
            ctx_sub.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        ctx_sub.beginPath();
        ctx_sub.moveTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x2,s.y2); 
        ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x3,s.y3); 
        ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x4,s.y4); 
        ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        if(draw){
            ctx_sub.fill();
            ctx_sub.stroke();
        }
            ctx_sub.restore();

        }
```

// draw a triangle around the circle --> but not run....

```
          function triShape(s,color,draw){
            ctx_sub.save();
            //ctx_sub.rotate(Math.PI * 2 / 12); 
        ctx_sub.fillStyle='rgb('+color+')';
            ctx_sub.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        ctx_sub.beginPath();
        ctx_sub.moveTo(s.x1,s.y1);
            ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x1,s.y1); 
        ctx_sub.lineTo(s.x2,s.y2); 

        if(draw){
            ctx_sub.fill();
            ctx_sub.stroke();
        }
            ctx_sub.restore();
        }

    ..
    ....
```

Comment: you could try to calculate the length from one point of the triangle to the center of the circle, keep rotating the triangle until you find the shortest distance. And to position the triangle, simply search for a location on the circumfrence

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using trigonometry:

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7domgxf4/

```
// variables to define the circle and triangle
var PI=Math.PI;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=100;
var triLength1=35;
var triLength2=18;
var triSweep=PI*2/3;
var rAngle=0;


function triCircle(){

    // calc triangle tip point (on circle's circumference);
    var x0=cx+radius*Math.cos(rAngle);
    var y0=cy+radius*Math.sin(rAngle);

    // calc outer side of triangle
    var tricx=cx+(radius+triLength1)*Math.cos(rAngle);
    var tricy=cy+(radius+triLength1)*Math.sin(rAngle);

    // calc remaining 2 triangle points
    var x1=tricx+(triLength2)*Math.cos(rAngle-PI/2);
    var y1=tricy+(triLength2)*Math.sin(rAngle-PI/2);
    var x2=tricx+(triLength2)*Math.cos(rAngle+PI/2);
    var y2=tricy+(triLength2)*Math.sin(rAngle+PI/2);

    // draw the circle and the triangle
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

**[ Addition ]**

You can calculate the angle of any point versus the centerpoint like this:

```
var dx= s.x1 - centerX;
var dy= s.y1 - centerY;

rAngle= Math.atan2(dy,dx);

triCircle();
```

Comment: You can calculate `rAngle` using your start, end or any other position. I show how in the addition to my answer.

Comment: sorry.... I did not solved.... i see you whole source.. may i have your email address?

Comment: triangle position mismath to my wish.... bacause i change the cavnas size like this...  wi =  canvas.width ;
    he =  canvas.height ;

 centerX = wi/2;
 centerY = he/2;

 radius = (he/2-he/30);

 orfSize = 124394;
 arg = 2*Math.PI/orfSize;

Comment: The size of the canvas has nothing to do with positioning the triangle.  Here's an example that lets you move the mouse to any x,y on the canvas and the triangle will be correctly positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qs6bkkw1/

Comment: I referenced this source --? http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/o5xp21t2/ and, but not use mouse event.. I use define position variable.. for example, ost=12762;oen = 16826;